# `execute()` hangs and eats memory

Tags: programming, qiskit

Used [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) to check why I get memory spikes in what I though were small circuits. The circuit itself is constructed using `qiskit.aqua.algorithms.single_sample.shor.shor.Shor`, the backend ended up being `ibmq_qasm_simulator` with the default number of shots (1024).

The results:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   302    180.6 MiB    180.6 MiB       @profile
   303                                 def _shors_period_finder(self, job_descriptor: ShorJobDescriptor, fleet: QFleet, shots=None):
   ...    ...            ...
   310    180.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           shor = Shor(N=9, a=4)
   311    324.0 MiB    143.4 MiB           circ = shor.construct_circuit(measurement=True)
   ...    ...            ...
   315    326.1 MiB      2.0 MiB           qcomp = fleet.get_best_backend(circ.n_qubits, job_descriptor.allow_simulator)
   ...    ...            ...
   324    668.9 MiB    342.9 MiB           job = execute(circ, backend=qcomp, shots=shots if shots else 1024)
   ...    ...            ...
```

Why am I getting the memory spike on line `324`?

Is a `(9,4)` Shor circuit really 143.4MB? Am I using the wrong `Shor` object?

Or am I just optimistic about the circuits I can construct without this volume of overhead?

Comment: Are you not receiving a response/result after executing the circuit? You say that it hangs as well.

Comment: I've got print statements before and after the `execute` call, yeah it hangs for at least 10 minutes. Circuit construction also takes over ten seconds

Comment: I tried running the code that I could from your post. It looks like the circuit being created is fairly large, so the time it takes to create that circuit is not too out of the ordinary. However, when I ran the job on he `ibmq_qasm_simulator`, it did not take too long. Do you have any more information about the code you are running?

Comment: Haven't reproduced the long execution time since yesterday

Comment: Hmm, might have just been a blip in the network during the time you originally were running. Should be fine if you are not experiencing the long wait time anymore.